# Papyrus template parameter

Tags: templates, acceleo, papyrus

I am trying to add template parameter to class without any success.
I want to make class that have template parameter like `Range<T>`.

Those Papyrus support that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does, but trough the graphical editor its a bit tricky.

i suggest you to read [1] and use the UML tree editor and reload the graphical view afterward.

Generics in UML is not as simple as it could be in Java.

[1] http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Defining-Generics-with-UML-Templates/index.html